# caching mechanisms for graphql responses

Tags: caching, graphql

I have a requirement to cache the responses to a new graphql query added to our exising schema.  From reading the docs at: [apollo docs](https://master--apollo-server-docs.netlify.app/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching/). I can see that I need to do one of two things:

1. statically add a schema hint to the query in the schema:

`type Query { latestPost: Post @cacheControl(maxAge: 10) }`

2. use a plugin like 'apollo-server-plugin-response-cache' to save full responses to a cache. [see here](https://master--apollo-server-docs.netlify.app/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching/#saving-full-responses-to-a-cache)

What I can't see, is the differences between these two implementations, or why I would pick one over the other.

Cache will be running in fargate, so no sharing across instances.

Is it how if I use the second method, the responses to all queries will be cached? I can't see any additional indicator inthe docs to say which particuar queries should be cached, once the plugin is imported.

Answer (score 1):

As already alluded to `apollo-server-plugin-response-cache' allows you to cache your response in-process, Redis, or with Memcached as opposed to simply behind a CDN or caching proxy. Using a shared caching layer may be of concern when running multiple instances of your server.

It seems `apollo-server-plugin-response-cache' becomes more critical where you need to segment your cache per user, as opposed to exposing to any or all consumers. As explained, '[r]esponses whose overall cache policy scope is PRIVATE are shared only among sessions with the same session ID.'

The cache control plugin provides the means to tell users apart by defining the required sessionId hook when instantiating apollo server:

```
import responseCachePlugin from 'apollo-server-plugin-response-cache';

const server = new ApolloServer({
  // ...
  plugins: [responseCachePlugin({
    sessionId: (requestContext) => (requestContext.request.http.headers.get('sessionid') || null),
  })],
});
```

So if your caching data, for example, a generally accessible leaderboard, then the plugin would not seem necessary unless you want to use Redis, etc. On the other hand, if the means to control private cache is needed (e.g., non-public stats for the particular authenticated user), or you need one of the noted specific cache sources to share across multiple containers the plugin appears a required dep.